# project working with ant, fails with maven

Tags: spring, web-services, maven, ant, jax-ws

We have a Spring Web Application project in production. For whatever the reason the client now wants to handle the project with maven. I tried to convert all the library jar files to maven dependencies. The application builds and gets packaged as war just fine, but when I deploy on my dev server(which is tomcat by the way, production server is also tomcat), it fails with this error:

```
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#2': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModelerException: runtime modeler error: Wrapper class ws.merchant.service.jaxws.InitializePayment is not found. Have you run APT to generate them?
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:149)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.ja

va:109)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:274)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModelerException: runtime modeler error: Wrapper class ws.merchant.service.jaxws.InitializePayment is not found. Have you run APT to generate them?
```

This is an error I know from other projects with web services. When I see this error, I create the wrapper classes using wsgen and add them to the web service in question.

EDIT ===========================

Here is the pom.xml

http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.company.library</groupId>
<artifactId>web app project</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.2.41.0</version>
<name>Maven Webapp</name>

<properties>
    <!--<webXmlPath>env/prod/web.xml</webXmlPath>-->
    <webXmlPath>web/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXmlPath>

    <springFrameworkVersion>3.0.7.RELEASE</springFrameworkVersion>
    <springSecurityVersion>3.1.3.RELEASE</springSecurityVersion>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>project.local</id>
        <name>project</name>
        <url>file:${project.basedir}/lib</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
        <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.pjl-comp-filter</groupId>
        <artifactId>pjl-comp-filter</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.company.library</groupId>
        <artifactId>jprov</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.company.library</groupId>
        <artifactId>transfer</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>nl.captcha</groupId>
        <artifactId>simplecaptcha</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xbean</groupId>
        <artifactId>xbean-spring</artifactId>
        <version>3.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
        <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${springFrameworkVersion}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${springFrameworkVersion}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${springFrameworkVersion}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${springFrameworkVersion}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${springFrameworkVersion}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${springFrameworkVersion}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${springFrameworkVersion}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${springSecurityVersion}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${springSecurityVersion}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${springSecurityVersion}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.maven-play-plugin.org.playframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>jj-simplecaptcha</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.7</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons.spring</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-spring</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>

        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <directory>dist-prod</directory>
    <outputDirectory>build</outputDirectory>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>web</directory>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
                <webappDirectory>web_maven</webappDirectory>
                <webXml>${webXmlPath}</webXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <sei>some.web.service.class</sei>
                <keep>true</keep>

            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>


</build>
```

But the problem is, I dont have this problem when deploying by Ant. I could use the web service just fine.

I am using jaxws-spring.jar for publishing Spring service as a web service. Am i missing some other dependency here? I have been wrestling with this conversion from Ant to Maven for three days, any other tip is also appreciated.

Comment: Without the corresponding pom file it's hard to guess what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Check your ANT build script to see if it runs "wsgen" somewhere.  Probably does and you will most likley need implement in your pom file.  If this is the case you can probably use use this plugin in Maven to generate the appropriate artifacts.

http://mojo.codehaus.org/jaxws-maven-plugin/wsgen-mojo.html

Check out this link which seems to describe what you are looking for:

http://www.techiekernel.com/2012/11/have-you-run-apt-to-generate-them.html